# -bash: pm2: command not found

Tags: node.js, centos, pm2

I have tried installing it in every way possible. I still cannot get it started.

```
whereis pm2
pm2: /usr/bin/pm2
```

I'm using CentOS6 for the first time on my VPS. I would really appreciate some help. My nodejs is up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify path to pm2 folder where the executable pm2 file exists.

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
export PATH="/location/Of/pm2/ExecutableFile:$PATH"
source ~/.bashrc
```

and then pm2 start.